# What is meant by the term "web stack?"

Tags: stack, web

While I see the relevance of "web" in the phrase "web stack," I'm left wondering what "stack" refers to in this context.

Answer (score 26, accepted):

It refers to the components or technologies/languages/operating sytems/etc used to build a web site.  For instance the "LAMP" stack is: Linux, Apache, MySQL, PHP

Comment: I guess for Microsoft, it's simply Microsoft Stack [or *The* Stack ? ;)]

Comment: No its a W(I|A)M(P) Stack "Windows (IIS|Apache) (My|MS)sql (PHP)"  And I would have to say that "*The* Stack" is LAMP as it has a masive market share.

Comment: To cite my source on the above comment about Apache's market share: http://news.netcraft.com/archives/web_server_survey.html

Comment: I've always heard either WINS or WISA for the all-Microsoft stack: Windows-IIS-.NET-MSS or Win-IIS-SQLSrvr-ASP(.NET). However, both of those are used for other IT-related technologies so there is the potential for confusion.

Answer (score 15):

"Stack" is slang used by programmers trying desperately to make the set of tools they use sound cool.

Comment: *Sound* cool?  But they *are* cool!  Right...?

Comment: @StevenA.Lowe .. and it is better that way ;) ..the last thing I need is nerdy teens on their phones talking about how "the web stack" sucks and how they cannot order a pizza or movie tickets on the damn phone because of that..

Comment: Too good. FYI, this answer showed up in the review queue for being low quality, but I absolutely refuse to recommend deletion. "Looks ok" to me. lol

Answer (score 13):

Stack is because the components pile up on top of each other

```
Your Application Presentation
Your Application Controls
Your Application Models
HTTP Server (Apache, IIS, etc.)
Database
Operating System
```

It's not strictly a stack (not like the OSI protocol stack).  But it's approximately a stack.

Comment: Is Apache always part of the stack? :)

Comment: I made it a bit more agnostic....

Comment: Apache is a web server. IIS is another one. Netscape Enterprise Server was another one.

 You can also have languages like Lisp which provide their own webservers, either implemented in Lisp or as apache/ISAPI/etc modules.

Comment: it's a stack like a stack of pancakes is a stack...